# Get accessor from another object from the JSF file

Tags: jsf-2, accessor

In my JSF 2.0 project i have 2 classes:

```
public class driver {  
    private String name = "Mr Taxi";  

    public String getName {  
        return name;  
    }  
}
```

...

```
import driver;  
public class CarBean {

    private Driver driver;  
    private String anotherProperty;  

    public String getAnotherProperty {  
        return anotherProperty;  
    }   
}
```

And the jsf file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
      "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
          xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
          xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
          xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">
    <h:body>
        The car has a driver with name: #{carBean.driver.name} <--------Focus on this one

    </h:body>
</html>
```

I know that the above example do not work. But is there any way to access the driver object getName method from the jsf file? Or do I have to make a new method "getDriverName" in the CarBean class?

Can you please help med guys? B.R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this example, its simple enough:

[Injecting Managed beans in JSF 2.0](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/injecting-managed-beans-in-jsf-2-0/)